# React/Firebase how to check if username exist in database

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm creating a game that user can login with just a username as a guest and play. Normally, when user visits the website I'm fetching all users data from firebase and assigning it to **users** state  and then if user click **Play** button I'm checking if username exist.

**Where I create function to fetch users using firebase**

```
import { async } from "@firebase/util";
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from '../firebase/auth';

export interface User{
    isUser: boolean;
    id: number;
    username: string
}

interface UserState{
    users:User[];
    isLoading:boolean;
    errorMessage:string;

}

export const fetchUsers = createAsyncThunk("users/fetchUsers", async()=>{
    const usersArray:User[] = []
    const usersRef = collection(db, "users");
    const q = query(usersRef, where("isUser", "==", true))
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>{
        const user = doc.data() as User;
        usersArray.push(user);
    })

    return usersArray;
})

const initialState: UserState = {
    users:[],
    isLoading:false,
    errorMessage:""
}

const usersSlice = createSlice({
    name:"users",
    initialState,
    reducers:{},
    extraReducers:(builder)=>{
        builder.addCase(fetchUsers.pending, (state, action)=>{
            state.isLoading = true;
        })
        builder.addCase(fetchUsers.fulfilled, (state, action)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.users = action.payload;
            state.errorMessage = "";
        })
        builder.addCase(fetchUsers.rejected, (state, action)=>{
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.users = [];
            if(typeof action.error.message === "string" ){
                state.errorMessage = action.error.message
            }
            
        })
    }
})

export const usersActions = usersSlice.actions;
export const userReducer = usersSlice.reducer
```

**where I fetch all data**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(guestInputActions.changeInputValue(randomUser))
    dispatch(fetchUsers()) 

  }, [])
```

**Where I check if user exsits**

```
const handleGuestLogin =  () => {
    async function checkIfUsernameExist() {
      if (users) {
        const existUser = users.find((user: User) => user.username === inputValue.toLowerCase())
        if (existUser) {
          dispatch(userLoginActions.setLoginStatus(false))
          dispatch(userLoginActions.setErrorMessage("This username already exists!"))
          return
        } else {
          dispatch(userLoginActions.checkUserName(inputValue))

        }
      }
    }
 
   checkIfUsernameExist();

  }
```

But I don't think it is efficent way. I want to fetch all users data when user click play button not on initial render. But when I try to do that with async/await my users array always empty before I check if username exists. So, user can play game even username is in already database

What I tried to fetch users data when user click **Play** button (not on initial render)

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(guestInputActions.changeInputValue(randomUser))
  // dispatch(fetchUsers()) commented out this line

  }, [randomUser])
```

```
const handleGuestLogin = async () => {
    async function checkIfUsernameExist() {
      if (users) {
        const existUser = users.find((user: User) => user.username === inputValue.toLowerCase())
        if (existUser) {
          dispatch(userLoginActions.setLoginStatus(false))
          dispatch(userLoginActions.setErrorMessage("This username already exists!"))
          return
        } else {
          dispatch(userLoginActions.checkUserName(inputValue))

        }
      }
    }
   const val = await dispatch(fetchUsers());
   checkIfUsernameExist();

  }
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm overlooking something, but I don't immediately see any calls to a Firebase API in the code you shared. Is the question really *about*, or do you just happen to be *using* Firebase and is the question actually just about ReactJS flow?

Comment: It's my misake. I edited question to show where I use firebase @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Thanks. That helps. I'm still not sure if I understand the concrete question you're asking is, though that may now be because I am not an expert on thunks and dispatching to them. --- On the Firebase side: If you want to check if a document with a specific user name exists in Firebase, I'd recommend doing so with a query: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries